# SQL Server join on to tables

Tags: sql-server, left-join

Please help me with the following problem:

SQL Server 2012 database

**Table 1 (T1)**

```
*******************************
| pk_Id | text | fk_t2 | fk_t3|
*******************************
|   1   |text1 |    1  |  null|
*******************************
|   2   |text2 |    2  |  null|
*******************************
|   3   |text3 | null  |  1   |
*******************************
|   4   |text1 | null  |  2   |
*******************************
```

**Table 2 (T2)**

```
***************
| pk_Id | col1| 
***************
|   1   |5285 | 
***************
|   2   |6621 | 
***************
```

**Table 3 (T3)**

```
************************
| pk_Id | col1 | fk_t2 |
************************
|   1   | text1|    1  |
************************
|   2   | text2|    1  |
************************
|   3   | text1|    2  |
************************
```

What i need:
T2.Col1    T3.Col1   T1.Text

Like you see, T2 is related with T3, and both, T2 and T3 are related with T1.
in T1, column text are stored values for both tables (t2 and t3) when in text column is a value for t2 the fk_t3 is null (i know bad design), and when in text column is a value for t3 the fk_t2 is null.

I know that don’t work:
 (returns nothing)

```
select t2.col1, t3.col1, t1.text 
from t2
inner join t1 on t2.pk=t1.fk_t2
inner join t2 on t3.pl=t1.fk_t3
```

returns null in t3.col1

```
select t2.col1, t3.col1, t1.text            
from t2
left join t1 on t2.pk = t1.fk_t2
left join t3 on t3.pl = t1.fk_t3
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `left join`

```
select t1.text,
       t2.col1,
       t3.col1           
from t1
left join t2 on t2.pk = t1.fk_t2
left join t3 on t3.pl = t1.fk_t3 or t3.fk_t2 = t2.pk_Id
```

Comment: thank you! your solution (coalesce) dont return the t3.col1, just mix it togheter with t2.col1.  i need to have t2.col1 and t3.col1 on distinct collumns. Maby i don't understand :). i need t1.text, t2.col1, t3.col1 in the return

Comment: Then just do that. I updated the answer. But one of them will be null according to your question and I thought you wanted just the non-null value - no matter from which table. But the updated query seperates the columns.

Comment: that was the first thing that i have made. t3.col1 is all null in the result :)

Comment: no. i will try to modify my question with a table schema. thank you

Comment: i have modified my question, hope that this help you to understand better my problem. First i have forgot to mention about T2>T3 relation.

Comment: Updated the answer. But it looks like you don't need the relation from t1 to t3.

Comment: Thank you for your help! With your help i was able to get what i need. All the best!